# Trouble using react to make a user sign in/sign up page with authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui

`App.JS file`

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom"

import SignIn from './pages/SignIn.jsx';



function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SignIn />}/>
        <Route path="/sign-up">
          Signup
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`SignIn.jsx file`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

function Copyright(props: any) {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary" align="center" {...props}>
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://mui.com/">
        Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const theme = createTheme();

export default function SignInSide() {
  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    console.log({
      email: data.get('email'),
      password: data.get('password'),
    });
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container component="main" sx={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Grid
          item
          xs={false}
          sm={4}
          md={7}
          sx={{
            backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundColor: (t) =>
              t.palette.mode === 'light' ? t.palette.grey[50] : t.palette.grey[900],
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
          }}
        />
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
          <Box
            sx={{
              my: 8,
              mx: 4,
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
          >
            <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
              <LockOutlinedIcon />
            </Avatar>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
              Sign in
            </Typography>
            <Box component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                autoFocus
              />
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                label="Remember me"
              />
              <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
              >
                Sign In
              </Button>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs>
                  <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                    Forgot password?
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                    {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Copyright sx={{ mt: 5 }} />
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

The output in the browser is a completely blank page. What I was expecting was a simple login and signup template for the user. I used source code from a material ui sign in side template, from the website https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/templates/.

The errors in the jsx file (keyword any on line 16, React.FormEvent line 32) are caused by a "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files error". So I tried to change the file to a .tsx, Which solved the errors in the file but still did not give me the output I was looking for in my browser.

In the App function in the App.js file I tried replacing keyword Switch with routes, but I did not see the change I was looking for.

The webpage is supposed to output a simple SignIn and Signup template. The tutorial I am following is https://medium.com/@sanderdebr/building-a-workout-tracker-with-react-and-firebase-part-2-authentication-220e5b863d5b. His code is outdated which is why im running into problems, Im using this tutorial as a prototype project to familiarize me with new technologies react, firebase, material ui.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Specifically: please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [reactrouter docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes) if you are using v6 + you shouldn't use `Switch` anymore (I think they remove it entirely and that is why the last error pops up). The `<Switch>` component was replaced by `<Routes>`.

Also as you can see in the previous link form reactrouter docs instead of childrens you should use the property `element={...}` from `<Route`

(so something like
`<Route path="/sign-up" element={<Signup />} />`
. Or to match your case something like `<Route path="/sign-up" element={"Signup"} />`)

There might be other issues as well (this were the ones that stood out). But without a minimal reproducible example is kind of hard to tell